# Error while connecting Logstash and Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am very very new to ELK, I installed ELK version 5.6.12 on CentOS sever. Elasticsearch and Kibana  works fine. But I cannot connect Logstash to Elastic search.
I have set environment variable as

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_131
export PATH=/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_131/bin:$PATH
```

I run simple test :

```
bin/logstash -e 'input { stdin { } } output { elasticsearch { host => localhost:9200 protocol => "http" port => "9200" } }'
```

I get error :

```
WARNING: Could not find logstash.yml which is typically located in 
$LS_HOME/config or /etc/logstash. You can specify the path using -- 
path.settings. Continuing using the defaults
Could not find log4j2 configuration at path 
/etc/logstash/logstash.yml/log4j2.properties. Using default config which 
logs errors to the console
```

Simple "slash" mentioned in official documentation of Logstash works like following :

```
$bin/logstash -e 'input { stdin { } } output { stdout {} }' 
Hello
WARNING: Could not find logstash.yml which is typically located in 
$LS_HOME/config or /etc/logstash. You can specify the path using -- 
path.settings. Continuing using the defaults Could not find log4j2 
configuration at path /usr/share/logstash/config/log4j2.properties. 
Using default config which logs errors to the console
The stdin plugin is now waiting for input: {
"@version" => "1",
    "host" => "localhost",
"@timestamp" => 2018-11-01T04:44:58.648Z,
"message" => "Hello" }
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Hi, in your simple test above `host => locslhost:9200` I see you have misspelled localhost. In your second attempt with stdin & stdout are you referring to the warning ? You ran logstash and gave input as 'Hello' and what do you see ? Run your logstash command with `--log.level debug` and see if you see any helpful logging to see what is going on

Comment: Hello, I updated the question. I changed locslhost:9200 to localhost:9200. and I still get same error. I tired command  $bin/logstash -e 'input { stdin { } } output { stdout {} }' --log.level debug. Again same error.

Comment: When you say error, are you referring to the warning above ? You can ignore the warning. Did you wait for logstash and main pipeline to start ? Can you run logstash as root and wait for it to start and then enter input after you see the prompt `The stdin plugin is now waiting for input:` ?

Comment: If i ignore the warning for Simple slash then it's okay. But what about simple test I run to see connection between logstash and Elastic search? This one :  ' bin/logstash -e 'input { stdin { } } output { elasticsearch { host => localhost:9200 protocol => "http" port => "9200" } }' 'Does  output mentioned in above question for this command means Logstash is connected to Elastic search?

Comment: Run the simple test command as root with —log.level debug and wait for logstash to start. If there are errors you should see on the console. If no errors, then enter the input when prompted and check your elasticsearch to see if data is indexed or not

Comment: You mean this command? : 'bin/logstash -e 'input { stdin { } } output { elasticsearch { host => localhost:9200 protocol => "http" port => "9200" } }' - -log.level'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182917/discussion-between-ben5556-and-sayali-k).